# Encoding two categorial data present in same dataset in Deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset where there is one colomn name 'reason', other is 'issue'.
i wanted to encode it as;

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
reason_no_enc = enc.fit_transform(temp['REASON NO'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
issue_enc = enc.fit_transform(temp['Issue'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
```

But i realized it is creating problem, the later one **issue_enc** is considered encoded, when i try to inverse reason_no_enc, it generates error.

how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use different instances of OHE for each column like this:

```
# fit encoder using 'REASON NO' data
# later use this instance of OHE to decode 'REASON NO' data
ohe_reason = OneHotEncoder()
reason_no_enc = ohe_reason.fit_transform(temp['REASON NO'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

# fit encoder using 'Issue' data
# later use this instance of OHE to decode 'Issue' data
ohe_issue = OneHotEncoder()
issue_enc = ohe_issue.fit_transform(temp['Issue'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
```

And also you can use one instance of OHE for both categories like this:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()
encoded_arr = enc.fit_transform(temp[['REASON NO', 'Issue']])
```